# User not found in sharepoint director

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, error, active-directory

> We're sorry, but ******* can't be found in the *******.sharepoint.com directory. Please try again later, while we try to automatically fix this for you.

I have removed the user, waited 24 hours, re-added the user. Please keep in mind that this is an External User. And still no go. When I see the user in my directory and click on the name it says:

> User can not be found

Any ideas? Spent 1 hour with Microsoft Support and got no where.

Regards,
Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps we've done to resolve this that work for us:

- Delete the user from group 0, `/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0`
- Delete the user from the tenant admin center or via PowerShell with `Remove-SPOExternalUser`
- Reshare with the external user

Comment: As per https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_shareon-mso_o365b/site-is-not-access-by-extranet-user-user-not-in/5bf85849-dbeb-4994-8c8e-2c7845bb01a7 and https://practical365.com/exchange-server/permanently-remove-deleted-users-office-365/, the first step needs to be done for EACH site collection the user is in. The second step will require PowerShell since the admin center doesn't allow you to remove users from the recycle bin.